# Class error 'A function body must be provided'

Tags: flutter, class, dart

All I am trying to do is add a new class that contains a list of strings. Everything is working except I am getting an error on my class saying it needs a function body on the last '}'. I followed a tutorial and it matches almost exactly. On the tutorial the code did not need a 'required' statement before the parameters. After adding the 'required', those errors went away but the function body error remained. This is the code:

```
class LoginInfo {

  String website;
  String username;
  String password;

  LoginInfo(
      {required this.website, required this.username, required this.password})

}
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of your `constructor`.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you forgot add a `;` at the end of the constructor.

The problem goes away doing that:

```
class LoginInfo {

  String website;
  String username;
  String password;

  LoginInfo(
      {required this.website, required this.username, required this.password});

}
```